# Highlighting cell when selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableView, and i can select multiple records. When i click more that 1 record the cell should get highlighted. i have attached my code below; What hapence now is that when i click on multiple records it higlights, but when i try to remove it (as in click the same row again), a different cell gets un-highlighted. Why is this ?

But if i replace the `[cell setHighlighted:YES animated:YES/NO];` with `[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];` everything works properly. How can i fix this ?

I have added code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
     [cell setHighlighted:YES animated:YES];

} 
else {
       [cell setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`, as it is intended for this purpose.

Comment: Will it be an issue if i use my own way? will the app get rejected by appStore?

Comment: @Illep you are much more likely to get rejected, but it depends on the extent of how you use your own purpose

Comment: @blake305, i don't think so it will get rejected because of this.

Comment: I don't think Apple will reject purely on the basis that the standard checkmarks are not used. It will be reviewed based on how you implement the cell highlight; how obvious the highlight is, and whether the app maintains a good UX.

Answer (score 2):

According to apple developer documentation for selecting more than one row you should use .

```
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

and for Deselect

```
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Why is this, will my app get rejected if i use another way ? and could you please link me the dev doc that says this?

Comment: Your app will not reject because of this but its good to use Checkmark rather than setHighlighted:YES.

Comment: i would greatly appreciate if you could you please post a link of the apple dev documentation where it says this?

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, highlighting is not the preferred way to do this.  Users want a consistent experience across apps, which is why the Human Interface Guidelines recommend using a checkmark to indicate row selection: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW42 (Table 7-1)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the UI issues being raised, the problem you are experiencing *may* be due to your table cells being reused, and retaining the highlighted state from the record that was previously displayed in that cell.

I suggest you keep a separate record of indexes/id's for those highlighted. You should then always check against this, rather than the state of the cell itself. (You can use NSArray or other collection class depending on your needs).

In **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** you should also check this array and set the highlighted state accordingly.